# Copy cell values from one spreadsheet to a second AFTER the second has been named after the first

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have two different spreadsheet templates;  a Sales spreadsheet composed of several linked tabs
(Formulas work fine and we like the layout). We also have a Management Spreadsheet with several interlinked tabs(formulas work and we like the layout on this one too).

They are both templates that we copy, rename, and use for each new project while preserving the originals and associated formulas as "Blank Sales templates" and "Blank Management Templates" respectively.

Not all projects that we create proposals for actually get contracted so, often times we do not utilize the management Template at all. When we do, we have a script that allows us to copy, name, and place the Management Spreadsheet from a button inside the Sales spreadsheet. This works fine but only the Sales file name is copied to the Man File and we ' d like to copy over cell data as well.

When the "Copy Man. File " button is clicked from the Sales File, we want specified cell values from the Sales File Cover Sheet to copy over to different cells in the  Man file cover sheet. Looks easy...Sounds easy....it Aint!

Both the Man. Spreadsheet and Sales Spreadsheets contain summary-like, "Cover sheet" tabs and although the data between them is mostly redundant, it is not formatted the same. 
I Suspect that this cannot be done this way because we need to copy the data over as the new file is created. Can anyone at least confirm this is possible?

Here is the code so far:

```
 function CreateManFile9() {        
  var copyMan = DriveApp.getFileById("Man. Template").getId();    
  var toFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Man. Template folder");       
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();  
      //button in one cell of active sheet runs this script
  var sheetName = sheet.getRange('B3').getDisplayValue();                // 
   //Can't we grab additional cells, at this point, and copy them over too?

 DriveApp.getFileById(copyMan).makeCopy(sheetName, toFolder);
```

}

Comment: So what are the ranges that you want to copy?  And do you wish to have the formats copied with them or just the values?

Comment: Hello Cooper! Cells B4,B5, B10, D11, and E4 from the Active sheet to B8, B10, D15, E3, and J14, respectively to the copied Man. file. Ideally, at the time of the final comment in my code. Can we do it at that time in that place in the code or does it require different approach? And, at this point, I think just values will be fine.

Comment: So, the question is: how do you ask apps script to 1) get cells in the active sheet and, 2) copy the values into a different sheet and into different cells of the second sheet. With .get methods, I cannot grab specified cells and then send them to other specified cells of a different Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
function copyValuesSrcToDes(srcId,srcshname,srcrgA,desId,desshname,desrgA) {
  var src=SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcId);
  var srcsh=src.getSheetByName(srcshname);
  var des=SpreadsheetApp.openById(desId);
  var dessh=des.getSheetByName(desshname)
  srcrgA.forEach(function(sA1,i){
    dessh.getRange(desrgA[i]).setValue(srcsh.getRange(sA1).getValue());
  });
}
```

srcId - Source Spreadsheet Id

srcshname = Source Sheet Name

srcrgA - An array of cells to copy from in A1 notation

desId - Destination Spreadsheet Id

desshname - Destination Sheet Name

desrgA = An array of cells to copy to in A1 notation

This is what I think you need to do:

```
function CreateManFile9() {        
  var copyMan = DriveApp.getFileById("Man. Template").getId();    
  var toFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Man. Template folder");       
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();  
  var sheetName = sheet.getRange('B3').getDisplayValue();                // 
  var file2=DriveApp.getFileById(copyMan).makeCopy(sheetName, toFolder);  
  var srcId=copyMan;
  var srcshname=sheet.getName();
  var srcrgA=['B4','B5','B10','D11','E4'];
  var desId=file2.getId();
  var desshname=SpreadsheetApp.openById(desId).getSheets()[0].getName();
  var desrgA=['B8','B10','D15','E3','J14'] 
  copyValuesSrcToDes(srcId,srcshname,srcrgA,desId,desshname,desrgA)
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know it is possible. I have not tested it yet but can this code  be added to what I have so far at the last comment (of My code) or does it preserve and add to the existing functionality? We are trying to copy relevant cell data over at the time the file is made...that is, at the time function createManFile9 is run.

Comment: Using an array to transfer the data had occured to me but I have not found a way to make this work WITH the existing function. Is THAT possible?

Comment: It's a function.  Give it the correct parameters and it will do the transfer for you.

Comment: `srcrgA=['B4','B5','B10','D11','E4']`  `srcrgB=['B8','B10','D15','E3','J14']`

Comment: but its not working cooper. Where do i put your code into my existing code to make it work? Did you notice the existing code and functionality?

Comment: the issue is that the source ID is the Active sheet but what is being copied is template that gets a new id each time. It s at this time that we want to copy the cell data from Active sheet into the new (different,copied) spreadsheet.

Comment: I really don't know because your code doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Interesting. It works just fine. We just need to ALSO copy several cells over to the newly copied file which has different formatting. It seems that a review of my question would help you...just the English part.  It may also be that I cant do this with just one function.

Comment: So, Just to articulate a little better, We have a file (Sales)  from which we copy a dfferent file (Management) into a different folder. When we copy the Man file, the current code takes the value from cell B3 and that becomes the name of the Man. file. We'd like to also take values from OTHER cells and transfer them to different cells in the newly copied Man. file. Thats all.

Comment: also, The English part of my question depends on clear distinction between the words "Sheet", "SpreadSheet", "File" and "Folder". I DONOT use them interchangebly.

Comment: You should summarize better the question, it's hard to understand.
I'm sure a lot of people here can help you, but first you have to help them to understand the question.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask